# Como contar o numero de "rows" em uma tabela em python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite3

Exemplo, tenho um banco de dados chamado 123, nesse banco de dados tem a tabela jogadores, que seria onde ficam as contas dos jogadores.
Quero contar quantas contas existem no banco de dados.

Enfim, contar o numero de rows de uma tabela SQLITE3, usando PYTHON 2.7.

O que tenho até agora:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import sqlite3

# Connexion for database
try:
    print "Tentando conectar-se ao banco de dados."
    Database, Cursor = None, None
    Database = sqlite3.connect("./database/database.db", check_same_thread = False)
    Database.text_factory = str
    Database.isolation_level = None
    Database.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    Cursor = Database.cursor()
    print "Conectado com o banco de dados.\n"
except:
    print "[ERROR] Falha na conexão do banco de dados."
```

Cursor.execute("?")

Comment: Ok, o que você já tem de código até agora? Já conseguiu conectar-se com o banco com Python? Deu algum erro? Você sabe SQL?

Comment: Att: Codico att
Tenho conexão, sem erros na conexão.
Sobre o codico não tenho =/

Comment: E quanto ao SQL? Você sabe como é feito uma consulta com SQL?

Comment: Sei muito pouco sobre SQL, mais sei sim Deletar, atualizar, inserir valores em tabelas. Consulta também.

Comment: Tente executar a consulta: `select count(*) from jogadores`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criando banco de dados contendo uma tabela de jogadores com 3 registros:

```
import sqlite3

jogadores = [ { "id" : 1, "nome" : "Joao" }, { "id" : 2, "nome" : "Maria" }, { "id" : 3, "nome" : "Jesus" } ]

conn = sqlite3.connect('foobar.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE tb_jogador ( id integer, nome text );")

for j in jogadores:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_jogador ( id, nome ) VALUES ( %d, '%s' );" % ( j["id"], j["nome"] ))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Recuperando quantidade de registros contidos na tabela:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('foobar.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT count(1) FROM tb_jogador')

count = list(c)[0]

print("Quantidade de jogadores registrados: %d" % (count) )

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Você também poderia fazer isso:

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM jogadores')
count = len(cursor.fetchall())
```

o fetchall() pega todas as linhas de sua tabela e as coloca em uma tupla, todas elas dentro de uma lista. Então é só colocar o len para contar quantos valores tem dentro dessa lista.
:)

site: https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/

cursor.fetchall(): busca todas as linhas de um resultado de consulta. Ele retorna todas as linhas como uma lista de tuplas. Uma lista vazia é retornada se não houver nenhum registro para buscar.